# Maven & Jenkins order classpath alphabetically, but not locally

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm currently facing severe classpath problems with Jenkins 1.532.2 and Maven 3.0.3. Locally, the classpath order is correct and all JUnit test work. On Jenkins though, the classpath is ordered alphabetically, not like in the pom defined.

Output of `mvn dependencies:build-classpath` on Jenkins (partly redacted):

```
axis/axis/1.4/axis-1.4.jar
axis/axis-wsdl4j/1.5.1/axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
com/company/ownlibrary.jar
com/microsoft/sqljdbc4/3.0/sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.1.0/ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
commons-codec/commons-codec/1.5/commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-discovery/commons-discovery/0.2/commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
junit/junit/4.11/junit-4.11.jar
log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
org/apache/axis/axis-jaxrpc/1.4/axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
org/apache/axis/axis-saaj/1.4/axis-saaj-1.4.jar
org/apache/poi/poi/3.8/poi-3.8.jar
org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
org/mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
org/objenesis/objenesis/1.0/objenesis-1.0.jar
org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
```

This is the output of `mvn dependencies:build-classpath` locally executed (partly redacted):

```
com\oracle\ojdbc6\11.2.0.1.0\ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
org\apache\poi\poi\3.8\poi-3.8.jar
commons-codec\commons-codec\1.5\commons-codec-1.5.jar
de\company\xyz.jar
de\company\xyz2.jar
com\company\own.jar
log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar
commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar
com\microsoft\sqljdbc4\3.0\sqljdbc4-3.0.jar
axis\axis\1.4\axis-1.4.jar
org\apache\axis\axis-jaxrpc\1.4\axis-jaxrpc-1.4.jar
org\apache\axis\axis-saaj\1.4\axis-saaj-1.4.jar
axis\axis-wsdl4j\1.5.1\axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
commons-discovery\commons-discovery\0.2\commons-discovery-0.2.jar
org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.5\slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
junit\junit\4.11\junit-4.11.jar
org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
org\mockito\mockito-core\1.9.5\mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
org\objenesis\objenesis\1.0\objenesis-1.0.jar
```

I use Maven 3.0.3 so it should use the pom-defined ordering of dependencies.

What can be the source of this problem and how can I solve this?

Additional info: As you can see on the classpath items, I'm building locally on Windows and Jenkins runs on a Linux OS.

New information: The Maven process on Linux also does not work correctly. I tried to build it locally on the machine, on which Jenkins runs, and the result is the same. The classpath is ordered, although I tried Maven 3.0.3 and 3.2.1

Comment: If you really must use a 3.0.x version, please at least use `3.0.5`.

Comment: I checked with 3.2.1 on Linux, too. I'm updating the question with the new information

Comment: I am somewhat new to Maven, but is the JDK on both environments the same? I am not sure if this is relevant, but I had some issues recently with order being messed up since locally they were included in my JDK, but server had previous version and had to pull in the newest common-lang jars etc based on a dependency for them that wasn't met by server JDK.

Comment: @AndrewCampbell Yes, it would be highly relevant. But the JDKs are the same version. They are not the same, as they are on Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Maven to 3.2.1 helped with the sorting classpath, but not the classpath problem. The classpath is not sorted anymore on Jenkins, but the resources are loaded in a false order nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, class path order should not matter. If you have issues, it means you are loading more than one version of the same jar. You should not rely on class path order.
You should understand why it happens and if you cannot avoid it, use the `mvn dependency:tree`  to figure out where the "bad" jar is coming from, and add an exclude in the dependency that's responsible for it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, I can only suspect that it is a classpath order thing, as a third-party library loads XML files. And the loaded files are different on Linux and Windows, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: -1: I rarely down-vote, so here's why I did: This is poor advice. Classpath ordering does matter. With small projects which don't have messed up dependencies, your statement may be true, unless these dependencies have shaded libraries inside them as well. The ordering of the dependencies on the classpath is crucial and one should always keep it in mind, esp. when dealing with third-party libraries like the ones mentioned above, as you have little to no control over them. And, yes, you must check your `dependency:tree` and add exclusions where possible, or override with explicitly defined ones.

Comment: @carlspring, I accept your comment, but still insist that you should control the content of the classpath and not let classpath control you. The order is implemented differently between servers and you take a risk relying on it. IMHO...

Comment: @EldadAK: I fully agree with you that applications should not rely on classpath ordering. Unfortunately, some libraries ship files which should not be shipped (log4j.properties, application-context.xml etc.) For this you have to be very carefull and must control your classpath.